# Web server conncetion status

Tags: mysql, iis, windows-server-2016

I am new to Windows server and SQL servers.

I have this situation I have two virtual servers one for IIS and one for SQL. I want to connect my IIS site to my SQL server who is on the different virtual server. I have set connectionString with my own SQL server parameters. But it seems like something is wrong it won't connect.

I can connect to SQL server with SSMS and everything works well.

Is there any way to see why web server (IIS site) can't connect to SQL server. Any logs maybe on the web server? For example, wrong address, don't have permission.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? You need to resolve ambiguity in your question first.

Comment: I edited my question. I use SQL server.

Comment: Post your connection string. In most cases, you hit the famous Kerberos delegation issue, and you should Google existing posts.